# Is there a way to exclude from Stack Exchange Data Query posts that I have already viewed?

Tags: support, search, data-explorer

I want to become better at answering questions and making useful comments. My problem is that I've only been developing for a few years. I feel like I have the most to offer someone who has a low reputation. I found and extended this query, and it works well. I want to improve it by excluding the posts I've already reviewed. Any suggestions?

```
select top 100 p.id as [Post Link], p.score, p.viewcount, p.answercount, p.tags,
  u.reputation
from posts p, users u 
where p.owneruserid = u.id
  and p.answercount = 0
  and u.reputation <= 100
  and p.deletiondate is null
  and p.creationdate < GETDATE() - 2
  AND(
      p.tags like '%angular%' OR
      p.tags like '%google-api%' OR 
      p.tags like '%google-people%' OR
      p.tags like '%google-photos-api%')
order by p.creationdate desc
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way. Stack Exchange does not store who viewed a question, only (approximately) *how many* views a question has had. Therefore, SEDE doesn't know it either.

However, if you regularly run that query and visit some of the questions, you'll notice that questions you already viewed have a different link color than the others; this is your browser reminding you which links you already visited (in my case, all but the second and fifth):

[image]

Comment: I did notice this. I try to run the query at least once a day and make a meaningful comment or answer a question. Some days I'm just too busy :) Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible.

In SEDE only viewcount is kept on a Post for PostTypeid = 1 (Questions). In the public schema which loggedin user viewed a Q/A isn't recorded and I doubt it is even kept in the internal schema. At best it could be reconstructed by examining the access logs but that is a SE dev only feature and then only when there is a need for it (for example when verifying bugs).

The best you can do is use the "favorite" function of the site. If you click the star found under the voting buttons of the question your "vote" will be recorded in the Votes table as a row with votetypeid = 5 and the userid will be populated. That is one of the few cases where the userid is not null in the votes table. There is also a favorite tab in your userprofile that serves the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'd also thought of that, but I'm not sure I want the list of my favorites to include these questions. I use this list for items I frequently return to because of the useful content. I think I will just shrink the date range. Since my goal to help with one question a day, I only need a day of questions.